# Are there any basic templating preprocessors that I can use for nginx configuration files?

Tags: command-line, scripts, software-recommendation, configuration

I've been using nginx variables to simplify my templates for a few years now. It turns out this is apparently a "rather slow" way of doing things and that my static configuration should be static.

With this in mind I would like to change to a situation where I have a `nginx.conf.template` file (or something like that) which I can run a command against —on my server— to generate a real configuration file.

My requirements are really simple:

- Simple variable substitution. So I can have [something like]:

  ```
  SITE=oli
  DOMAIN=oli.example.com
  ------
  server {
      server_name ##DOMAIN##;
      ssl on;

      ssl_certificate /web/##SITE##/ssl/##DOMAIN##.crt;
      ssl_certificate_key /web/##SITE##/ssl/##DOMAIN##.key;

  ...
  ```

  I have to stress that the syntax above is completely made up on the spot. Just an example of how I'd imagine doing this.
- Includes. Pull a file in ***AND*** (that's super-extra-important) also perform substitution.
- Something simple. I'm lazy and I hate configuration. `m4` looks lovely and all but zomg, I don't want to learn a new language just to configure a server. I'd rather just set the nginx manually if that's the trade-off.

This isn't specific to nginx, but that's what I'm using it for here. I'm just looking for a nice, simple command-line templating preprocessor. What have we got?